# Insert function in maxHeap has unwanted behavior

Tags: java, heap

have an insert function that should insert an element into the heap.

```
public void insert(int element) {
    Heap[++this.size] = element;
    int i = this.size;
    while (Heap[i] > Heap[parent(i)]) {
        swap(i, parent(i));
        i = parent(i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        System.out.println(Heap[j]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

The for loop with the print statements is for sample output, I'll get to that. parent(i) gets i/2, and size is the current heap size.

And this is the swap function:

```
private void swap(int first, int second) {
    int buffer = Heap[first];
    Heap[first] = Heap[second];
    Heap[second] = buffer;
}
```

The sample elements I am inputting are 950, 800, 850, 900, 850, 1000. The for loop in Insert() is meant to show the values as I put them (with a new line between each insertion).

[image]

I don't understand why the value of 800 is being set to 0. Then it is reinstated as 800, but is set to 0 thereafter. What part of my code is giving it this functionality?

Comment: Why was this question downvoted?

Answer (score 1):

The problem in your `insert` method is right here:

```
Heap[++this.size] = element;
int i = this.size;
```

So the first time you call `insert`, your array looks like this:

```
Heap[0] = 0
Heap[1] = 950
```

`this.size` is 1, and you start your sifting up the heap at index 1.

This can only end badly. After the second insert, your array contains `[950,800]`, and `this.size` is equal to 2. Now, let's see what happens with the third insert, when you insert 850.

```
Heap[++this.size] = 850
```

So `this.size` is incremented, making it 3. The value 850 is inserted at `Heap[3]`, giving you `[900, 800, 0, 850]`. That corresponds to this heap:

```
        900
       /   \
     800    0
    /
  850
```

Your code correctly rearranges the heap, giving you:

```
        900
       /   \
     850    0
    /
  800
```

Which corresponds to the array `[900, 850, 0, 800]`.

The problem is that you're incrementing the size *before* inserting the element. You need to increment *after* inserting. And then, because it's 0-based, you want the starting index to be `size-1`.

Here's the corrected method.

```
public void insert(int element) {
    Heap[this.size++] = element;
    int i = this.size-1;

    while (i > 0 && Heap[i] > Heap[parent(i)]) {
        swap(i, parent(i));
        i = parent(i);
    }
    for (int j = 0; j < size; j++)
        System.out.println(Heap[j]);
    System.out.println();
}
```

By the way, in a 0-based heap, the parent of node i should be `(i-1)/2`.